# Python Multiple Process with SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a program in python that load files into Google Bigquery. To load multiple files at once, multiple process can be launched at the same time (not threads). There can be up to 20 process running at the same time.
For control which file is being loaded, I'm using a SQL Server 2017 database.

Each process does the following steps (Simplified):

a. SELECT ID,Filename FROM QueueTable WHERE file_status='Not Loaded'
b. UPDATE QueueTable SET file_status='Loading' WHERE file=ID
c. Load the file into Bigquery, using BQ LOAD

for the b) Step, I'm using this function:

```
def set_loading_file(self,ID):
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                    'Server='+self.server+';'
                    'Database='+self.database+';'
                    'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql_query=f'''UPDATE QueueTable SET status='Loading' WHERE ID={ID}'''
    cursor.execute(sql_query)
    cursor.commit()
```

It works most of the time, but sometimes, the program loads the same file twice.
I've tried adding a random time before the first select, but the trouble keeps happening.

What is wrong with the logic? How can I solve it?

I think that for some reason, the process reads a file ID when another process has readed the same file ID, but still not updated the status it in the database.

Thanks!

Comment: You have a common race condition. Each process needs to retrieve and update the desired row in one logical step and without allowing any other process to retrieve the same row. If you search on that term you will find examples of how to avoid this. But it is strange that you have some sort of control program that does not start each process with an "assigned" row - which would avoid (mostly) this issue.

Comment: Thanks, you're right! I have the Select and the Update in different statements, that are not inside a BEGIN/END TRANSACTION and I'm not locking the row. I can't mark you answer as correct because it is a comment.